# Is there anyway to reduce FBSDKCoreKit size?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am using Swift 2.1 and the last Facebook SDK. The problem is yesterday I uploaded the app to test it via TestFlight and I saw that its size was around 28Mb.

My question is if someone know how to reduce FBSDKCoreKit size, because it is around 19 Mb. There are many other apps using Facebook login and its size does not exceed 10-11 Mb.

I just want to let people login in my app with Facebook, and currently I am using FBSDKCorekit and FBSDKLoginKit.

Answer (score 1):

FBSDKCoreKit is a fat framework:

```
➜  FacebookSDKs-iOS-20160115 lipo -info FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
Architectures in the fat file: FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit are: i386 armv7 x86_64 arm64
```

You can remove the i386 (simulator) part of this framework to reduce the file size using the `lipo` tool:

```
lipo -remove i386 FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit -output FBSDKCoreKitNoSim
```